# IF Else method, inside a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have this NSString with format:

```
comandoInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO fazerbem_clients (image) Values('%@')", list[0]];
```

but most times the array list can be empty, causing a problem in the compiler, so I would like if possible to add a method if else within it, in a way that if the array is empty there he puts an empty string as **@""**

I tried this way just does not work:

```
comandoInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO fazerbem_clients (image) Values('%@')", [list[0] : @""] ];
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
comandoInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO fazerbem_clients (image) Values('%@')", list.count ? list[0] : @"" ];
```